# Почему не срабатывает durationChanged

Tags: python, qt, qmediaplayer

Пытаюсь подключить слайдер к треку, чтобы можно было перематывать трек и следить за временем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на item'ы liTracksList'а должен начать играть трек, но перед этим мне нужно узнать длительность этого трека чтобы установить sTrackSlider.Maximum.

Я почитал что это можно сделать с помощью durationChanged(), который срабатывает один раз и выдает длительность трека.
Но почему то сигнал на durationChanged никогда не срабатывает. Что я делаю не так?

```
import sys, os
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from design_player import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore
class Player(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.tempPlayer = QMediaPlayer()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.changeMode(1)
        self.tempPlayer.play()

        self.tempFolder = None
        self.tempTrack = None
        self.tempTrackList = list()
        self.ui.bInitSelect.clicked.connect(self.selectInitFolder)
        self.ui.liTracksList.itemClicked.connect(self.onItemClick)
        self.ui.bTrackStop.clicked.connect(self.pauseTrack)
        self.ui.bTrackPlay.clicked.connect(self.playTrack)
        self.ui.bTrackNext.clicked.connect(self.nextTrack)
        self.ui.bTrackPrev.clicked.connect(self.prevTrack)
        self.tempPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.update_position)
        self.ui.sTrackSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.tempPlayer.setPosition)
        self.tempPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.show()

    def selectInitFolder(self):
        self.ui.liTracksList.clear()
        self.tempTrackList.clear()
        self.tempFolder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
        self.tempTrack = self.tempFolder.split('/')[-1]
        self.tempFolder = self.tempFolder.split(self.tempTrack)[0]
        for file in os.listdir(self.tempFolder):
            if file.split('.')[-1] == 'mp3':
                self.tempTrackList.append(file)
        if self.tempTrackList:
            for item in self.tempTrackList:
                self.ui.liTracksList.addItem(item.split('.')[0])
        self.setFixedSize(300, 433)

    def onItemClick(self, item):
        self.tempTrack = item.text()
        path = self.tempFolder + self.tempTrack + '.mp3'
        self.tempPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        self.ui.lTrackName.setText(str(self.tempTrack.split('-')[1].strip()))
        self.ui.lTrackSinger.setText(str(self.tempTrack.split('-')[0].strip()))
        self.tempPlayer.play()
        self.changeMode(0)

    def pauseTrack(self):
        self.tempPlayer.pause()
        self.changeMode(1)

    def playTrack(self):
        self.tempPlayer.play()
        self.changeMode(0)

    def update_position(self, position):
        print("position =" + str(position))
        self.ui.sTrackSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.ui.sTrackSlider.setValue(position)
        self.ui.sTrackSlider.blockSignals(False)

    # 1 - play, 0 - stop
    def changeMode(self, mode):
        if mode:
            self.ui.bTrackStop.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.bTrackStop.setVisible(False)
            self.ui.bTrackPlay.setEnabled(True)
            self.ui.bTrackPlay.setVisible(True)
        else:
            self.ui.bTrackPlay.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.bTrackPlay.setVisible(False)
            self.ui.bTrackStop.setEnabled(True)
            self.ui.bTrackStop.setVisible(True)

    def nextTrack(self):
        pos = self.tempTrackList.index(self.tempTrack + '.mp3')
        pos = 0 if (len(self.tempTrackList) - 1) == pos else pos + 1
        item = self.ui.liTracksList.item(pos)
        self.ui.liTracksList.setCurrentItem(item)
        self.onItemClick(item)

    def prevTrack(self):
        pos = self.tempTrackList.index(self.tempTrack + '.mp3')
        pos = (len(self.tempTrackList) - 1)  if pos == 0 else pos - 1
        item = self.ui.liTracksList.item(pos)
        self.ui.liTracksList.setCurrentItem(item)
        self.onItemClick(item)

    def update_duration(self, duration):
        print("duration = " + str(duration)) # Никогда ничего не выводит
        print("maximum slider = " + str(self.ui.sTrackSlider.maximum())) # Никогда ничего не выводит
        self.ui.sTrackSlider.setMaximum(duration)
        print("maximum slider = " + str(self.ui.sTrackSlider.maximum())) # Никогда ничего не выводит

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Player()
    window.setFixedSize(300, 50)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать модуль `design_player.py`

Comment: Разве проблема в этом? У tempPlayer же срабатывает positionChanged.

Comment: если вам действительно нужна помощь - пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Может быть из-за смешения библиотек PySide6 и PyQt5

Comment: Попробовал поменять все библиотеки на pyqt , не помогает( @AlexanderChernin

Comment: Arcanecliff неужели вы не понимаете, что для того чтобы проверить работу вашего приложения и дать вам ответ или какие-либо рекомендации - нужен минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alexander_Chernin Был прав, в *.py файле дизайна были смешены библиотеки PyQt5 и PySide6, оставил только PyQt5 и сигнал durationChanged() сработал.